# Eclipse does not copy correct jar to server deployment folder with classifier

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, jboss

I'm using latest Eclipse (Kepler, build: 20140224-0627) and a simple jar project. One jar have classifier and another not - like

- `project1-SNAPSHOT0.1.jar`
- and `project1-SNAPSHOT0.1-no-cdi.jar`.

Then I have in my second project included dependency `project1-SNAPSHOT0.1-no-cdi.jar`, declared with classifier.

When I make `maven install` on second project built war file is OK and contains under `WEB-INF/lib` folder all expected jars. But then if I try to publish second project through Eclipse to the JBoss EAP 6.2 deployment folder there isn't any `project1-SNAPSHOT0.1-no-cdi jar` file, but instead `project1-SNAPSHOT0.1.jar` - not correct, should be jar with classifier.

Does anyone knows why is that happening to me? Am I missing some configuration properties under Eclipse or Maven? Is this maybe any known bug?

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem by recreating all workspace metadata. Seems to be some eclipse plugin related problem. Anyway, I created new workspace and everythings now works like a charm.